# Create and operate on a label: image with Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I have a set of ImageMagick commands which I am attempting to convert to Python's Wand package, and I am having trouble replicating the `label:` operator.

My commands (with all the unnecessary operations removed) are as follows:

```bash
magick in.jpg -size 3200x1800 \
  \( -pointsize 100 -fill white label:"Example" \
    \( +clone -background "black" -shadow 95x3+10+10 \) \
    +swap -background none -layers merge +repage \
  \) -geometry +100+100 -composite \
  out.jpg
```

My Wand implementation is as follows:

```py
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='in.jpg') as img:
    img.resize(3200, 1800)

    with Image() as label:
        with Drawing() as draw:
            draw.font_size = 100
            draw.text(0, 0, 'Example')
            draw(label)

            shadow = label.clone()
            shadow.background_color = 'black'
            shadow.shadow(95, 3, 10, 10)

            label.sequence.append(shadow)
            label.sequence.append(label.sequence.pop(0))

            label.transparent_color('none')
            label.merge_layers('merge')
            label.trim()
            label.reset_coords()

        img.composite(label, left=100, top=100)

    img.save(filename='out.jpg')
```

However, this gives an exception on `label.clone()` of

```
wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-10' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickDrawImage/3093
```

When I'd expect the drawing (text) to be placed onto the image (label).